# Access 2010 and ODBC connections

Tags: sql-server, database, odbc, ms-access-2010

I have a server (2008R2) that has little Access (2010) databases relevant to departments and their needs.  I have a new EHR server (2008R2) running SQL (2008R2) servers and am able to establish an ODBC connection between the two.  I created the ODBC using the SA / SA password to the SQL Server.

As an administrator, I can log in to the Access database and run queries and reports based off of tables linked back to the SQL DB.  No one else can. I did save the password when I created the External table link in Access.  My Sys Admin - also Administrator, cannot run queries or reports logged into the Access database server for this DB.

On this particular SQL Server, I am not an admin under my login. I have to use the SA account to login to the backend or through the Management Console.

I need to have the EHR managers run their own reports.  Does anyone have any experience with why the ODBC would not be allowing a connection for anyone but me when the connection is server based?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what you mean by "the connection is server based". Do you mean that you created an ODBC DSN on the server where the Access databases reside? If so, then that could help explain the issue because the DSN name may not exist on (at least some of) the workstations where the Access database is being opened.

Answer (score 0):

What Gord Thompson said is important. Access is not a database server and its engine runs on the client machine which will need copies of whatever DSNs are used.

But the problem of getting Access to 'remember' credentials is something I recall struggling with in Access 2000. My solution was to create a dummy pass-through query (anything that will run quickly) that stores the credentials. When a new client session starts, first call the dummy query and for the duration of their connection, they'll have access to the DSN in question.